# is there a way to sort numerical values in STUFF/FOR XML PATH?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using STUFF and FOR XML PATH to list values from a column, and it's working fine. I'm using DISTINCT as otherwise I get duplicates; the only problem I have is that it's giving me the values listed alphabetically and I want them listed numerically. E.g. I get "5, 569, 6" and I'd prefer it to be "5, 6, 569". I've tried using ORDER BY but that doesn't work, because of the DISTINCT. (The code below is actually part of a larger query, which has multiple joins, which is why I've got DISTINCT in several places.)
Please can someone point me in the right direction?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT IndData.UserID,
        STUFF ((
            SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CAST(InnerTable.AgentID AS varchar(6))
            FROM 
            IndData AS InnerTable
            WHERE InnerTable.UserID = IndData.UserID
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,2,'' )
        AS [AgentIDs]
```

Comment: Add an order by to your subquery.

Comment: This is one of the techniques used to aggregate strings. SQL Server 2017. introduced [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for this. Even in earlier versions though you can add an `ORDER BY` clause in the inner query, *before* the data gets converted to strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your values are already distinct for the list, you can apply `ORDER BY` like following.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT IndData.UserID,
        STUFF ((
            SELECT ', ' + CAST(InnerTable.AgentID AS varchar(6))
            FROM 
            IndData AS InnerTable
            WHERE InnerTable.UserID = IndData.UserID
            ORDER BY InnerTable.AgentID
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,2,'' )
        AS [AgentIDs]
```

[Sample Demo](https://rextester.com/ERSDI64118)

If the AgentIds are not distinct, you can have a inner table of distinct record and after that you can put ORDER BY, you can check following sample.

[Sample 2](https://rextester.com/SKP62232)

Comment: Thanks! I'd give you an upvote, but I'm new so I can't.  The first one didn't work, I got this error:  ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified. 
So I used your Sample 2, which worked perfectly. It looked like this after I'd amended it for my situation:                
  STUFF ((
  SELECT  ', ' + CAST(AgentID AS varchar(6))
   FROM
   ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT
    InnerTable.AgentID 
    FROM
     IndData as InnerTable
     WHERE InnerTable.UserID = IndData.UserID
   ) t
   ORDER BY AgentID
    FOR XML PATH('')
   ),1,2,'' )
  AS [AgentIDs]

Comment: You need to remove DISTINCT if you want to use order by in the inner query